# GARCH and future volatility monte carlo simulation

Tags: python

Im trying to run a rolling volatility (GARCH) using this python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

class monte_carlo:
    def __init__(self,S,mu,sigma,c):
        self.S=S #The start value of the portfolio 
        self.mu=mu #The expected return calculated by CAPM
        self.sigma=sigma #Volatility 
        self.c=c #Confidence level 

    def brownian_motion(self, num_sim, pred_days):#Main function to rund MCS
        last_price = self.S #Collect the start value from init function 

        # There is a need of a dataframe to create the plots
        simulation_df = pd.DataFrame()

        #Loop to simualte the number of needed simulations 
        for x in range(num_sim): #Loop to ensure start value as value day 0
            #Ensure the loop to start with start value
            count = 0

            #Create empty list 
            prices = []
            #Append the start value to the list at position 0
            prices.append(last_price)

            for i in range(pred_days): #The actual MCS
                if count == 251: #Restricting the simulation to one year
                    break
                shock = ((self.mu-0.5*self.sigma**2)+self.sigma*np.random.normal())
                # The brownian motion 
                price = prices[count] * np.exp(shock) 
                #Calculate price after shock 
                prices.append(price)
                #Append price to the list 
                count += 1 #next count
            simulation_df[x] = prices 
            #When loop is done, add the prices to the data frame 
            self.simulation_df = simulation_df
            self.predicted_days = pred_days

    def plot(self):
        pred_days = self.predicted_days
        simulation_df = self.simulation_df
        last_price = self.S
        #recall values 
        plot_line = plt.figure() #call lot function 
        style.use('bmh') #set style 

        title = "Monte Carlo Simulation: " + str(pred_days) + " Days"
        plt.plot(simulation_df) #plot all the price paths
        plot_line.suptitle(title,fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
        plt.xlabel('Day')
        plt.ylabel('Price ($USD)')
        plt.grid(True,color='grey')
        plt.axhline(y=last_price, color='r', linestyle='-')
        #ˆCreate right font
        plt.show()

    def VaR(self): #funtcion to callculte VaR
        simulation_df = self.simulation_df
        #Recall price an list of price paths 
        price_array = simulation_df.iloc[-1, :] #Rename 
        price_array = sorted(price_array, key=int)  #Sort final prices
        percentile = np.percentile(price_array,(1-self.c)*100) 
        #Use percentile function to find the percentile at
        #The given confidence interval 
        Value_at_Risk = 1-(percentile/self.S) 
        #Calculate the acutall value at risk
        print("Value at Risk: ", Value_at_Risk)

        '''#fit = stats.norm.pdf(price_array, np.mean(price_array), np.std(price_array))
        #plt.plot(price_array,fit,'-o')
        plt.hist(price_array,normed=True)
        plt.xlabel('Price')
        plt.ylabel('Probability')
        plt.title(r'Histogram of Speculated Stock Prices', fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
        plt.legend(loc="upper right")
        plt.show()'''

if __name__== "__main__":

    S = 100000000
    c = 0.99
    mu = 0.00024
    sigma = 0.02

    sim = monte_carlo(S,mu,sigma,c)
    sim.brownian_motion(1000, 10)
    #sim.plot()
    sim.VaR()
    #sim.key_stats()
    #symbols = ['AAPL', 'KO', 'HD', 'PM']
    #weights = [1000,1000,2000,3000]
    #sim.get_portfolio(symbols, weights)
    #sim.get_asset('AAPL')
```

Can someone help me with this implementation?

Comment: what do u want? be clear

Comment: Is struggle to implement the constant changing volatility into my MCS. Rn the code relies on a constant volatility and rate of return, but i would like to make this more dynamic